# How to select the entire row where the row id is the maximum

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to select all columns from my table in the row where the row id is the maximum. Here is my query so far.

```
select * from 
       ( select row_id, max(row_id) over () as max_row_id
       from qa_swab_calendar )
       where row_id = max_row_id;
```

This query returns the desired row but not all columns and I can manually add each individual column like so

```
   select * from 
       ( select row_id, date, actions, max(row_id) over () as max_row_id
       from duties_calendar )
       where row_id = max_row_id;
```

My question is how can I select all columns for this one row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just want

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.*,
               max(row_id) over () as max_row_id
          FROM table_name a)
 WHERE row_id = max_row_id
```

Frequently, you'd do something like this instead

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 WHERE row_id = (SELECT max(row_id)
                   FROM table_name)
```